# Pandas dataframe select top largest 90%

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which is constructed through a groupby which looks something like this (only a selection:

```
                   Weight   WeightPerc
Flow    Prod                        
Export  A           1       0.05
Export  B           9       0.45
Export  C           1       0.05
Export  D           2       0.1
Export  E           7       0.35
Import  A           1       0.05
Import  B           9       0.45
Import  C           1       0.05
Import  D           3       0.15
Import  E           6       0.3
```

In reality the Prod (products) can be a few hundred and the percentage can range from 0.01% to 10%. I would like to select the top 95% (ordered largest to smallest) per Flow to take out the products that hardly contribute to the total. How would I do this?

Comment: using `cumsum`? `df.sort_values(by=weightperc)` then `s=df.WeightPerc.cumsum()` and `df[s < 0.95]`

Comment: Just noticed your percentages do not add up to 100%, is thar correct?

Comment: @RafaelC change the s to `s=(df.sort_values('WeightPerc',ascending=False).WeightPerc.groupby(level=0).cumsum()<0.95)
` and `df.loc[s[s].index].sort_index()
` it will be the right answer

Comment: @Wen oh I see, exports sum up to 100% and imports sum up to 100%, good catch

Comment: Thanks @Wen this works nicely!

Comment: @Yorian yw:-) happy coding